# Exchange 2010 Certificate Renewal

Tags: exchange, ssl, certificate, exchange-2010, outlook-web-access

I am still learning how to configure Exchange 2010, so I hope that you can help me on some topics.

The certificate for `mail.xxxxxx.com` has expired. The previous IT guy had `OWA` set up on the server, but it is only used rarely and by one person.

My main question is: Why is the certificate needed? And, lets say I disable `OWA`, is the certificate no longer needed?

The domains registered under this certificate are:

- `autodiscover.xxxxxx.com`
- `[myServerName]`
- `mail.xxxxxx.com`
- `[myServerName].xxxxxx.local`
- `xxxxxx.local`

I am confused on where these domains are used and how (besides `mail.xxxxxx.com`).
Also, where do I see which services/roles are used, and what is the domain or URL that are using in order to complete the  wizard below?

[image]

Comment: From @AndrewScott: You can follow this step-by-step beginner guide for renew Exchange 2010. Just go through the url and check, it is easier to follow. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-renewal-exchange-2010.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this step-by-step beginner guide for renew Exchange 2010. Just go through the url and check, it is easier to follow. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-renewal-exchange-2010.htm

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the link becomes invalid.

Comment: I know I can give here complete description for validation of the link, but if we can suggest a helpful resource to someone, then what's wrong with it? I believe the resource I provided here, had work at-least.

Comment: Answers are expected to be self-contained and definitive so they stand on their own and don't become obsolete if a link is unavailable.  Helpful suggestions can be posted as a comment, which you need a little more rep for.  I moved the info to a comment so that it isn't lost in case this post gets deleted as a "link only" answer.  You might want to delete the answer so it doesn't get downvoted as low quality, which would eat into your rep.